# How to Convert point Csv file into point cloud(.pcd format)

Tags: python, point-clouds, lidar, lidar-data

here is how csv looks
[Lidar csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MbeF.png)

help me with it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question. :)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. I don't know what columns i, t, d stand for, in the lidar file. For .pcd you need to write a file like this: https://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.html . Is there a programming language which you know and which you might use to write a small program that does the conversion?